# Need to filter out duplicated data using latest date from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, duplicates

For example:

I have

```
Name    Gender   Check-in     Place
Steve   Male     2019-10-04   Denmark
Steve   Male     2010-08-04   Denmark
Steve   Male     2020-09-09   Denmark
Susan   Female   2017-07-27   Finland
Susan   Female   2015-02-12   Finland
```

I need only latest date value

```
Name    Gender   Check-in     Place
Steve   Male     2020-09-09   Denmark
Susan   Female   2017-07-27   Finland
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

Firstly convert your **'Check-in'** column value to datetime dtype by using `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['Check-in']=pd.to_datetime(df['Check-in'])
```

Now You can use `sort_values()` method and `drop_duplicates()` method:

```
resultdf=df.sort_values('Check-in',ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Name'],ignore_index=True)
```

**OR**

You can also do this by `sort_values()` method , `groupby()` and `reset_index()` method:

```
resultdf=df.sort_values('Check-in',ascending=False).groupby('Name').max().reset_index()
```

Now if you print `resultdf` you will get your desired output